How to do conditional `import` in Webpack 5?
I'm building an app which has a server running in node, and a client running in browser. Both of them depend on a common utility file. This utility file needs one specific part to exhibit different behaviour between the server and client.
The (extremely) reductive version of what I'm trying to accomplish here is:
server.js
import util from './util.js`;

const x = await util.foo();
// do server-side things with `x`

client.js
import util from './util.js`;

const x = await util.foo();
// do client-side things with `x`

util.js
async function foo() {
  if (process.env.CLIENT_BUILD === 'true') {
    console.log('WARNING results in run-time error if this runs on server.');
  } else {
    console.log('WARNING results in build/bundle-time error if this is done on a client build.');
  }
}

For the server, this is not an issue, because the env var is picked up, and the appropriate branch is executed.
However, for the client, this is an issue, because at bundle time, the line with the console.log needs to not even be processed by webpack - and skipped entirely.
I've found several references indicating that the way to accomplish this used to be via process.env ... however this does not seemed to work in practice, and webpack attempts to build/bundle both branches of the if conditional statement.
What is the current recommendation for this, that works with Webpack 5?
(specifically I'm using webpack@5.91.0 via @vue/cli-service@5.0.8)
Refs:

Answer demonstrating conditional require, which involves the use of webpack.DefinePlugin, 2022/04: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36783411/194982
Comment on answer, which states "Webpack replaces node-like environment variables (i.e. process.env.SOMETHING) at build time.", 2020/03 https://stackoverflow.com/a/60771923/194982


Off the top of my head I would be tempted to have 2 different versions of util.js  one each for the client and server. It will likely be easier to build 2 different versions with a hard-coded flag than trying to disambiguate using environment variables at runtime.

@phuzi I'm actually trying to disambiguate at build/bundle-time by webpack, not at run time. "trying to disambiguate using environment variables at runtime."

Found a workaround that solved my issue, which is to use import from ESM,
in combination with the webpack build-time hint, webpackIgnore.
(1) Split the server-only component into a separate file.
(2) Use an import function (AKA "dynamic import", and not to be confused with an import statement) to reference this separate file.
(3) Add an inline comment /* webpackIgnore: true */ between the opening parenthesis of import and the file name).
Example:
util.js
async function foo() {
  if (process.env.CLIENT_BUILD === 'true') {
    console.log('WARNING results in run-time error if this runs on server.');
  } else {
    const { serverOnlyBit } = await import(
      /* webpackIgnore: true */
      './server-only-bit.js'
    );
    serverOnlyBit();
  }
}

server-only-bit.js
export function serverOnlyBit() {
  console.log('WARNING results in build/bundle-time error if this is done on a client build.');
}

