# Redux + karma-webpack - cannot read displayName of undefined upon import of React.Component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, redux, react-redux, karma-webpack

I'm using [`karma-webpack`](https://github.com/webpack/karma-webpack) and I am refactoring a React Component to use in multiple places. I moved the component
 to it's own file, so I can import it and [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) it differently by applying `mapStateToProps` / `mapDispatchToProps` in the HOC I later include on my page.

Here's the scenario:

`EventTable` - `import`s EventTableComponent, exports `connect`ed / wrapped component
`MyEventTable` - `import`s EventTableComponent, exports `connect`ed / wrapped component
`EventTableComponent` - defines the props / behaviors shared to render the data rows

When I `git mv` EventTable to `EventTableComponent` and refactored the code so the `connected` stuff is in the HOCs, the tests start failing to import `EventTableComponent` **only in `karma-webpack`**.  Chrome works just fine and the view render perfectly. QA is happy, or would be, but my build fails.

The build is failing because `WrappedComponent` is undefined for the `EventTable` and `MyEventTable` components, which causes `connect` to throw the message in the synopsis (`cannot read displayName of undefined`), but I don't even import either of these files into my test!  Instead, it fails while karma webpack is building, but before running any tests.

I fixed the build locally by destroying the view and making a "fake" / "replacement" like this:

```
function EventTableComponent () { 
    return (<div>garbage here</div>);
}
```

The build passes.

The most confusing part in all of this? I don't even test the HOC *at all*.    I import just the EventTableComponent into the test, but `karma-webpack`, as suggested in [the Redux Documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/WritingTests.html#connected-components).

I've written a minimal example gist to illustrate: 
https://gist.github.com/zedd45/cbc981e385dc33d6920d7fcb55e7a3e0

Comment: Wout Mertens (from Webpack Gitter) suggested replacing the `imports` with `require`.  This caused the tests to pass, but the imports stopped working in the app, so the Component was not rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by tricking the module system.

```
// EventTableComponentWrapper.jsx

import EventTableComponent from './EventTableComponent';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
    module.exports = require('./EventTableComponent.test.jsx');
} else {
    module.exports = EventTableComponent;
}
```

I import this file in both HOC Components, and based on my environment variable, I get the right one, and Karma Webpack is tricked into not exploding.

I arrived at this conclusion based on a few leads, but credit goes to this SO Post: 
[Conditional build based on environment using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572380/conditional-build-based-on-environment-using-webpack#answer-34689642)

and also to Wout Mertens from the Webpack Gitter channel for tipping me off to the issue being ES6 Class Import / Export related.

Comment: This is still hacky, and I've love a better solution