# Use webpack to use specific file based on node environment

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack, environment-variables, vue-cli-3

I'm working on a Vue app (using cli 3).  A third party front end component requires a config file.  I would like to use different files depending on my node env but am unclear how to do this.  For example, my directory structure might have tree.production.js and tree.development.js.  In my main javascript, I can't seem to specify

```
import {tree} from `./assets/tree.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`;
```

I also can't use .env files to specify

```
import {tree} from `./assets/tree.${process.env.VUE_APP_TREE}.js`;
```

What I'd like to try is utilize webpack a la the vue.config.js to use the correct file and rename it to tree.js so in my code I can just specify

```
import {tree} from "./assets/tree.js"
```

Or really any best practices on how to achieve this pretty mundane and seemingly routine dev/prod switch.

Something like

```
//vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: config => {
    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
      // do something with tree.production.js...
    } else {
      // do something with tree.development.js
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The root of your problem is that ES6 `import` (and `export`) are statically analyzed - meaning, you can't have dynamic values like you are trying. You can try dynamic imports using the `import().then(module => ...)` syntax, but that's not really what you need here.

I think you are looking for [resolve.alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias). It would look something like this in your webpack config:

```
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'assets/tree': path.resolve(__dirname, `path/to/assets/tree.${process.env.NODE_ENV}.js`)
    }
  }
```

and inside your app you would import it like this:

```
import { tree } from 'assets/tree';
```

Comment: I see that `const something = require(\`./${dynamic}/file\`).default` works but cannot use `require(\`./${process.env.SOME_ENV}/file\`)` because process is not defined on the client.

Comment: @HMR - sorry, just seeing this comment somehow, but most webpack setups (ex. create-react-app) should resolve environment variables for you (I think because of [this plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/)). I just tested on a react project and `const foo = require(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? './bar' : './foo')` worked for me. But you are right, generally `process` is not available on the frontend.

Comment: `null-loader` is super cool.

Answer (score 0):

sorry to hear you are having trouble with this. You are right, you aren't going to be able to use the a static import solution to load your file. There are options out there though depending on what you plan to do with tree.js. I don't know what tree is, but I am assuming you are only concerned with running your code in a webpack environment.

So what options do you have, maybe consider one of these options:

### Dynamic imports

This feels to me the most likely thing you want, if you are able to use an async approach with your code, you can dynamically load your code (also take advantage of code-splitting):

- https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports
- https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/webpack-and-dynamic-imports-doing-it-right-72549ff49234

### Conditionally load via proxy

In this answer, Alejandro Silva has used a proxy file to conditionally load the file based on an ENV_VAR. You can configure webpack not to require impossible paths.

- [Conditional build based on environment using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572380/conditional-build-based-on-environment-using-webpack)

---

### Others that might fit your requirements

- [convict](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convict/v/1.0.1) - For loading and merging configuration

Comment: the dynamic imports worked well  Thanks!  And I'm glad to finally have a working example of how to lazy load components.  But because this particular component is the first one on app load, it is a little simpler to use resolve.alias based on [Ryan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/264794/ryan-wheale) answer.  Much less code.