# Use Webpack to require different app config file based on mode

Tags: typescript, webpack

I have a Webpacked TypeScript app that loads a json config file.  The project is in its infancy so we don't have a good config store in production yet, so we're storing our config files side-by-side: `config.json` and `config.dev.json`.

In my TypeScript, I want to be able to type

```ts
import Config from './path/to/config.json';
```

and if `--mode development` is passed into webpack, I want it to require `./path/to/config.dev.json`.

Is this possible with just Webpack or Webpack + tsconfig.json?

Comment: The answer you handed me works fine.  Thanks!

Comment: If you want to link it in an answer to this question, I'll mark that as the answer.  Otherwise, I can do it.

Comment: (As an answer, not a comment ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea from the answer below is to use the [webpack-define-plugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/define-plugin/)

### `webpack.config.js`

```
const argv = require('yargs').argv;
const webpack = require('webpack');

// Import all app configs
const appConfig = require('./path/to/config.json'); /* Base config */
const appConfigDev = require('./path/to/config.dev.json'); /* Development */
const appConfigProd = require('./path/to/config.prod.json'); /* Production */

const ENV = argv.env || 'dev';

function composeConfig(env) { /* Helper function to dynamically set runtime config */
  if (env === 'dev') {
    return { ...appConfig, ...appConfigDev };
  }

  if (env === 'production') {
    return { ...appConfig, ...appConfigProd };
  }
}

// Webpack config object
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.js',
  ...
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __APP_CONFIG__: JSON.stringify(composeConfig(ENV))
    })
  ]
};
```

### Usage in your application

```
const config = __APP_CONFIG__
/* config available in module scope */
```

#### Reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/43436223/6129793