# How to strip testing code when React JS is minified by for production?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In my React functional component, I use `useEffect` to do some debug logging, but I only want it when I am running in a non `--production` build.

```
// something like
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  // I want the contents of this block removed on production builds, but it is inside a function
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("authState changed", AuthStates[authState]);
  }, [authState]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("authToken changed", authToken);
    if (tokenExpiresOn) {
      console.log(
        `token expires in ${(tokenExpiresOn - Date.now()).toLocaleString()}ms`
      );
    }
  }, [authToken]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (tokenExpiresOn) {
      console.log(
        `token expires in ${(tokenExpiresOn - Date.now()).toLocaleString()}ms`
      );
    } else {
      console.log("tokenExpiresOn cleared");
    }
  }, [tokenExpiresOn]);
}
```

Comment: Looks like a good use case for a custom hook

Answer (score 1):

You can not declare hooks conditionally. You can declare on the top level  and you can put your business logic inside the hook, e.g below.

```
useEffect(() => {
   if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'){
    console.log("authToken changed", authToken);
    if (tokenExpiresOn) {
      console.log(
        `token expires in ${(tokenExpiresOn - Date.now()).toLocaleString()}ms`
      );
    }
 }
  }, [authToken]);
```

Comment: but does it strip it from the minified code though?  Since it will never reach that path?

Comment: @ArchimedesTrajano, It will be part of the code, but will not execute until it matches the condition.

Comment: OK my Q is to make sure it is stripped off the minified output.

Comment: Take a look on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28572380/conditional-build-based-on-environment-using-webpack

Comment: Is there a specific set of instructions on how to integrate that with a ReactJS build?